# Possible destructor after a variable assignment using reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, destructor, reinterpret-cast

I'm hoping that this isn't an utterly ignorant question, but I can't seem to find any information on a few snippets of code I've been coming across.

Instead of describing it, I'll just give an example:

```
auto x = reinterpret_cast<T*>(something->data * sizeof(T));
myResult = std::move(*x);
x->~T();
```

Note that this code exists within a template class, hence the `T`.

I have a general understanding of `reinterpret_cast<>` and `std::move().` However, I don't quite understand what the statement `x->~T()` means. Being more familiar with `C`, I thought it was a logical not of the returned value of `<datatype>()`. Looking at the syntax though, it makes more sense - to me at least - that it's a destructor of some sorts.

If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's an explicit destructor call.

Comment: x->~T(); is calling the destructor of T (which can be class A or B or C), whatever the class<T> was declared as.

Comment: `something->data * sizeof(T)` ... what?  Multiplication, followed by a `reinterpret_cast`?  That is a ... strange operation.  Throw in a + somewhere and it might make sense.

Comment: As some of the others have said in the comments here, it's an explicit destructor and the reason it's being called can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589025/why-is-the-destructor-call-after-the-stdmove-necessary

Comment: This example is insufficiently example-like to know what your program is supposed to do. But, yes, this is obviously a destructor call. The original object was probably constructed with _placement new_, someplace else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an explicit destructor, and it's is usually used in conjunction with placement new. Placement new overlays an object (instantiates an object) in memory that had been pre-allocated, and calls the constructor thereafter([see wiki article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)).